# Google chrome is changing css behavior

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have div class called rectangle and i wanted to make hover effect with transition using css, but Google browser dont let the hover works when the browser window is in fullscreen. I'm using Mac by the way.

this is how i'm doing the hover with css:

```
.rectangle:hover {
Background: #4CAF50;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: background 0.3s;
    -o-transition: background 0.3s;
transition: background 0.3s;

}
```

It works in Firefox and Safari browser in fullscreen, but google dont let it work in fullscreen and i dont know why. Please help me to fix this problem i'm not able to find a fix for it.

Comment: Tried only `background-color`?

Comment: Move the whole transition part to .rectangle instead of .rectangle:hover?

Comment: Dems, have you tried "Google"-ing `background` CSS? (in any browser). "CSS tutorials" might also help. Whenever your CSS doesn't work in Chrome, it is not Chrome that "changes CSS behavior", it is your CSS that is not valid. Or maybe it's valid, but you just expect it to work differently than it does.

Comment: I did try background-color, but that did not help...

Comment: Its a vaild problem. Try the online CSS3 Generator from http://css3generator.com/ and see by youself...

Comment: What's the `position` of the rectangle class?

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 advices for you:

- don't use uppercase in a property: `background` not "Background"
- replace `background` by the more specific `background-color`
- the [`:fullscreen`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:fullscreen) pseudo-class might be useful in your case

Comment: Thanks Knu! but that did not help to fix it... same problem